# how to works with forms in array with angular 2

Tags: html, forms, angular

I've been working with reactive form like I show in the link

```
 https://plnkr.co/edit/ApCn3YicMjfm2vhSOudj?p=preview
```

this is my form

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let index = index">
  <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)" [formGroup]="user">
    <label>
            <span>Full name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
          </label>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('required')">
      Name is required
    </div>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('minlength')">
      Minimum of 2 characters
    </div>
    <div formGroupName="account">
      <label>
              <span>Email address</span>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
            </label>
      <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('account').get('email').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('email').touched">
        Email is required
      </div>
      <label>
              <span>Confirm address</span>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Address" formControlName="confirm">
            </label>
      <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('account').get('confirm').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('confirm').touched">
        Confirming email is required
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="user.invalid">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

but my problem is that I have an ngFor, every time I submit the form it push the data to array.

How can I do if I want for example submit my first array and push the data to position 0 of my data array, if I submit my second form, it will push the data to position 1

But my second form should be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you wanna using form array like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'signup-form',
  template: `
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="users">
      <div formArrayName="data">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let user of fData.controls; index as i">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <label>
              <span>Full name</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
            </label>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('required')">
              Name is required
            </div>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('name').touched && user.get('name').hasError('minlength')">
              Minimum of 2 characters
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="account">
              <label>
                <span>Email address</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
              </label>
              <div
                class="error"
                *ngIf="user.get('account').get('email').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('email').touched">
                Email is required
              </div>
              <label>
                <span>Confirm address</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Address" formControlName="confirm">
              </label>
              <div
                class="error"
                *ngIf="user.get('account').get('confirm').hasError('required') && user.get('account').get('confirm').touched">
                Confirming email is required
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="user.invalid">Sign up</button>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  user: FormGroup;
  users: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.buildGroup();
    this.users = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array([this.user])
    });
  }
  get fData() {
    return this.users.get('data') as FormArray;
  }
  buildGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      account: this.fb.group({
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        confirm: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.fData.push(this.buildGroup());
    const {valid, value} = this.fData;
    console.log(valid, value);
  }
}
```

basically, we're using `FormArray` to handle array of data, then loop through it.

in template, each time you loop through array item, Angular will store current AbstractControl in `index` variable (in above is `i`).

you can see form in action here: https://plnkr.co/edit/E5Qzm85LksSCZAloXZz5?p=preview

The API document here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html

you can use `at`, `removeAt`, etc to access or delete at specific index.